# how can i change array of object to object of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to convert array of objects to object of array using javascript.

Here is the code

```
const data = [
{
  items: [
    {
      code: "location_list_page",
      icon: "environment",
      id: 1,
      link: "/configurations/locations",
      name: "Localisations",
    }
  ]
},
{
  items: [
    {
      code: "service_list_page",
      icon: "api",
      id: 5,
      link: "/configurations/services",
      name: "Services",
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to create this object:

```
const data = {
  items: [
    {
      code: "location_list_page",
      icon: "environment",
      id: 1,
      link: "/configurations/locations",
      name: "Localisations",
    },
    {
      code: "service_list_page",
      icon: "api",
      id: 5,
      link: "/configurations/services",
      name: "Services",
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to solve it using map in array method but it didn't work.

Anyone can help me please ???

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be solved using `map` function and `Object.assign()` and the spread operator

```
var new_data = {"items": data.map(x=> Object.assign({}, ...x["items"]))};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty straightforward use of `flatMap`:

```js
const data = [
{
  items: [
    {
      code: "location_list_page",
      icon: "environment",
      id: 1,
      link: "/configurations/locations",
      name: "Localisations",
    }
  ]
},
{
  items: [
    {
      code: "service_list_page",
      icon: "api",
      id: 5,
      link: "/configurations/services",
      name: "Services",
    }
  ]
 }
]

const result = {items: data.flatMap(x => x.items)};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks you Jamiec